# Search WHERE NOT function in mysql for a string?

Tags: php, mysql

I got the following Mysql command:

```
// Call on a random style ID to display in rating window which user hasn't seen yet.

$resultSet = $conn->query("SELECT pictureID,userID FROM styles WHERE NOT 
viewedByUser = (NOT LIKE '%$userID%')  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc() ){
    $rateableUserID = $rows['userID'];
    $rateablePictureID = $rows['pictureID'];
}
```

I want to use the WHERE NOT function to search through the field "viewedByUser" after a string that does not contain the same string as the variable $userID.

What options have I got here?

Comment: You are using double negation and you've got a syntax error too (`= (NOT LIKE`).  Try to simply use the NOT LIKE operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :-

```
$resultSet = $conn->query("SELECT pictureID,userID FROM styles WHERE
viewedByUser NOT LIKE '%$userID%'  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc() ){
    $rateableUserID = $rows['userID'];
    $rateablePictureID = $rows['pictureID'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `!=` instead of `NOT LIKE` and there is nothing called `WHERE NOT`

```
$resultSet = $conn->query("SELECT pictureID, userID FROM styles WHERE viewedByUser != $userID ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

Since they are email addresses, you can do:

```
$userId = 'abc@abc.com xyz@xyz.com';
$userId = explode(' ', $userId);
echo $userStr = implode("', '", $userId);
$resultSet = $conn->query("SELECT pictureID, userID FROM styles WHERE viewedByUser NOT IN ('" . $userStr . "') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: but the field 'viewedByUser' contains a long string with many emailadress which are seperated with a space. It doesn't recognise the variable $userID in that field and continious with the picked pictureID and userID :/

Answer (score 0):

If you need  a (not) like on the viewedByUser  you can simply use

```
"SELECT pictureID,userID 
 FROM styles W
 WHERE viewedByUser = NOT LIKE '%$userID%' 
 ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1";
```